# What is the "show only allowed groups" option in OS X Server?

Tags: osx-server

I can't find information on this anywhere, but there is a checkbox in the Server app for both users and groups that shows only "allowed" users or groups.  Currently, only "Workgroup" is designated allowed .

Any idea what this pertains to?

[image: Show Allowed Groups]